# Issue with removing duplicate Line Geometries in Postgre

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a grid created from points and I have to create a network topology on it to traverse through using shortest path algorithm. But, I'm having the following issue

[image: the diagonals have equal geometries]

these diagonals are part of the network but  while removing duplicates these diagonals are counted as same and removed together which shouldn't happen. Why do these diagonals have same "geometry" values?

Comment: That depends on your code ;-)
Sadly you didn't provide any snippets or examples to work with.
Just taking a wild guess: The diagonals endpoints are the corners of the square, right? Maybe these "duplicate points" are equal to a "duplicate geometry" in your code and therefore these diagonals get deleted?

Comment: share query you are using to remove duplicate

Comment: what i basically did was created a grid of points and created edges to and from every point to every 8 nearest points now this is one of the small box in my whole edge grid and apparently these diagonals have same geom values

Comment: DELETE FROM  edge_table; 
WHERE edge_gid IN (
    SELECT e1.edge_gid 
    FROM thr e1, thr e2
    WHERE st_Equals(e1.geom_line, e2.geom_line)
    AND e1.edge_gid < e2.edge_gid
);